# Using fields of referenced contacts in message

Tags: relationships, message-templates

When I have two contacts that have an employer/employee relationship in CiviCRM I can use the name of the employer in message templates when I sent messages with the `{contact.current_employer}` tag.

However I am currently seeing no way to get the name of a contact referenced through a custom relationship (say for example sibling) to use that in a letter. Is there any way to accomplish this in CiviCRM? Maybe something like `{relationship_123.display_name}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM, you can install [Fuzion tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens) extension. It provides lots of tokens for contacts like relationships, payments etc

Details can be found [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken#readme).